# When I open and run Android Studio, it displays these errors from the very beginning

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

6 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uR6Fh.png)

compileSdk 31

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.lifecycle"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

The above method did not work.
This error increases to 16 errors when changing the minimum SDK and maximum SDK ;

Comment: What does the actual error say?

Comment: this error :
6 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:

Comment: have you tried to change the targetSdk to 31 ?

Comment: Yes, but did not answer
The number of errors he made was 6, changed to 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure all dependencies in the project are at the latest version.
Make sure the dependencies used in the project are compatible.
Make sure your Gradle version is at the latest.
Make sure that the "google()" repository used in the project's "build.gradle" file is correctly defined.
Try rebuilding the project: select "Build -> Clean Project".
Try clearing the Gradle cache: select "File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and Restart".

> example

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
```

must be the samemust be the same

```
compileSdk 31
targetSdk 31
```

Comment: The problem is downloading Gradle.